# Dmax search for maximum date returns final date in the table and doesn't consider the criteria

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access front end with a SQL Server back end database. I have a table `[Month End]` with columns `ID`, `[Month End Date]`.

In VBA, I am trying to find the maximum date that is before the next Sunday. I get the next Sunday as a date. The DMax always returns the last date in the table and doesn't seem to look at the criteria.

This code worked until I moved the back end to SQL Server.

Code:

```
if Weekday(Now()) < 3 Then
   NextSunday = DateAdd("d", 1 - Weekday(Now()), Date)
else
   NextSunday = DateAdd("d", 8-Weekday(Now()), Date)

nextMonthEnd = DMax("[Month End Date]", "[Month End]", "[Month End Date] < #" & NextSunday & "#")
```

Comment: Check that you for the date fields of the tables use data type `DateTime`, not `DateTime2`.

Comment: I do use datetime on the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the last day of month, you can use this function

```vb
Public Function LastDayOfMonth(ByVal d As Date) As Date
    d = DateAdd("m", 1, d)
    d = DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d), 1)
    LastDayOfMonth = DateAdd("d", -1, d)
End Function
```

First it gets the first day of the next month and then subtracts one day to get the last day of the current month. This works independently of the number of days in a month.

Comment: I don't need the last day of the actual month.  I have a table that has the accounting months.  I need to find which accounting month we are in.  So I need the last date in the accounting month table that is before this Sunday.

Comment: Try to explicitly format the date as `"#" & Format$(date, "yyyy\/MM\/dd") & "#"` as there might be a dd/MM/yyyy vs. MM/dd/yyyy format problem. If this does not work, try to use a SQL-Server date format `[Month End Date] < '20210903'` as I suspect the DMax function to not translate the date format correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing a format on NextSunday:

```vb
NextSunday = DateAdd("ww", Abs(Weekday(Date, vbTuesday) >= vbTuesday), DateAdd("d", 7 - (Weekday(Date) - 1), Date))
NextMonthEnd = DMax("[Month End Date]", "[Month End]", "[Month End Date] < #" & Format(NextSunday, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```